# rake ts:configure rake ts:index thinking-sphinx-3.1.1 ruby-2.0.0 error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to configure a rails running application on my localhost. I have not used sphinx before. I have installed the sphinx-search on my Ubuntu machine and its service is running.

When i try to execute rake ts:index or rake ts:configure I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
rake ts:configure --trace
** Invoke ts:configure (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute ts:configure
Generating configuration to /home/baran/code/atdhe/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib        

/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:37:in `block in associations'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib    
/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:35:in `collect'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib                    /thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:35:in `associations'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:62:in `multi_from_associations'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib    /thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:9:in `multi?'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute.rb:4:in `multi?'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:18:in `collection_type'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:96:in `block in append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `each'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:132:in `prepare_for_render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:65:in `render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `block in render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `collect'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:53:in `render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `block in render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `collect'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:90:in `render'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `block in render_to_file'
/home/baran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
/home/baran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `render_to_file'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:13:in `configure'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/baran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/baran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@athde/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:configure
```

Here are the indices files:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :restaurant, :with => :active_record, :delta =>    ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do

  indexes school(:school_name), :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
  indexes school(:branch_name), :sortable => true, :as => :branch_name
  indexes school(:delta) => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
  has restaurant_info(:is_pick_up), :as => :pick_up, :facet => true
  has delivery_info(:is_delivery),  :as => :delivery, :facet => true

  indexes contact_info(:restaurant_name), :sortable => true

  indexes delivery_info(:delivery_charges), :as => :delivery_charges

  has school(:id), :as => :school_id, :facet => true

  has restaurant_categories(:id), :as => :restaurant_category_ids, :facet => true

  has restaurant_info(:min_order), :as => :min_order, :type => :float, :sortable => true

  has avg_rating, :as => :rating, :type => :integer, :sortable => true
  has ranking, :as => :ranking, :type => :integer, :sortable => true

  has delivery_info(:delivery_estimated_time), :as => :delivery_eta, :type => :integer, :sortable => true

      set_property :min_infix_len => 1
  set_property :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
end


ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :school, :with => :active_record, :delta =>         ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
  indexes :school_name, :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
  indexes buildings(:building_name), :sortable => true
  set_property :min_infix_len => 1
  set_property :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
end
```

Comment: Can you share your index definitions (in app/indices) as well?

Comment: ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :school, :with => :active_record, :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
  indexes :school_name, :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
  indexes buildings(:building_name), :sortable => true
  set_property :min_infix_len => 1
  set_property :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
end

Comment: Both Indices files are added in the question as well.

Comment: i have tried with ruby 1.9.3 but there is also the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your indexes slightly cleaned up:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :restaurant, :with => :active_record, :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do

  indexes school.school_name, :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
  indexes school.branch_name, :sortable => true, :as => :branch_name
  indexes contact_info.restaurant_name, :sortable => true, :as => :restaurant_name
  indexes delivery_info.delivery_charges, :as => :delivery_charges

  has restaurant_info.is_pick_up, :as => :pick_up, :facet => true
  has delivery_info.is_delivery,  :as => :delivery, :facet => true
  has school.id, :as => :school_id, :facet => true

  has restaurant_categories.id, :as => :restaurant_category_ids, :facet => true
  has restaurant_info.min_order, :as => :min_order, :type => :float

  has avg_rating, :as => :rating, :type => :integer
  has ranking, :as => :ranking, :type => :integer

  has delivery_info.delivery_estimated_time, :as => :delivery_eta, :type => :integer

  set_property :min_infix_len => 1
end

ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :school, :with => :active_record, :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
  indexes school_name, :sortable => true, :as => :school_name
  indexes buildings.building_name, :as => :building_name, :sortable => true

  set_property :min_infix_len => 1
end
```

Changes I made:

- `:sortable => true` removed from attributes (the `has` calls). Attributes are sortable by their very nature, so this option changes nothing.
- Removed the set_property call for deltas - this is done at the top of the index since TS v3 (as you're doing already).
- Removed a field that was referencing the delta column, which looked kind of like a delta setting.
- Changed column calls as symbols/method arguments to be method names - what you were using was required with Ruby 1.8, but now is not needed (and may be buggy) with TS v3 and Ruby 1.9 or newer.
- Made sure all fields and attributes referring to columns via associations had custom names (the `:as` option).

It's also worth noting that you shouldn't need to specify types for attributes if the columns being used are those types. So, if `avg_rating` *is* an integer, then you don't need the `:type => :integer` option for that attribute.

My guess it was the combination of field/delta setting that was the main cause of the problem, but give this a spin, see if that helps things.

Comment: please suggest the possibility is there any configurations errors?

Comment: has school.id, :as => :school_id, :facet => true 
this line is trowing the errors. Please tell me what is the wrong with this line? When i removed this line it worked fine.

Comment: Do you have the association `school` in your Restaurant model?